# Designing reports at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, report

i am developing a windows forms application which has several windows containing datagridviews using vb.net. The client just recently came up with the desire to be able to print the data of each of these tables.

Having succesfully designed and implemented my first report using Crystal reports a few months ago, my first instinct was to do this using crystal reports. However, because I already knew exactly which columns and data I wanted to present in my first report, I could design the report taking this into account, so this was no problem.

Now, the challenge is that I do not know the exact number of columns to be printed in the report before hand, so I'm afraid I'd have to design the report programmatically, so my questions are;

1. Is there any means of desgining a report programmatically? For example, can I, using only code, tell crystal reports to put a "table object" in the details section, then put a column named X, and another named Y? If possible, can someone point me to some sample code on how to do this or something similar?
2. If 1 is not possible in crystal reports, can someone point me to some other reporting software in which I could achieve 1, and if possible, how?
3. Am I approaching the problem reasonably or is there a much better and easier way in which I could achieve the clients desires?

By the way, I already provided the possibility to export the tables to excel, from which the client could print them as they wish, but it would appear they prefer fancier looking reports with logos and stuff as one could achieve in crystal reports.

I'll be extremely grateful with any help in implementing this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of doing this, one is hard the other easy. First let's get the hard one out of the way. CR has a fully functional library which lets you create reports almost from scratch. It's called the RAS library. But it's very complex and not the best thing for someone new to Crystal to undertake.

The next solution, and the easiest, is to create a report that has all the possible fields you could ever need and then use the ReportObject model to dynamically hide the fields you don't need to show. Thus, if you could have between 5 to 10 columns on your report, create all ten of them in the report. Then in your app, if you don't need the 10th column, hide it. Something like this:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument myReport;
myReport.Load("..your file...");
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject myField;
myField =(CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)HealthRounds.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["Field10"];
myField.ObjectFormat.EnableSuppress = true;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need it really dynamical and perhaps easier, take a look into [list & label](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/report-generator-List-Label).
the sample of what you need to do looks somewhat easy:

```
Proj.Open( @“c:\Reports\artikel.lst” ,  LlDomFileMode .Create,
  LlDomAccessMode .ReadWrite, true );

ObjectReportContainer container= new
  ObjectReportContainer (Proj.Objects);

container.Position.Left = “0” ;
container.Position.Top = “0” ;
container.Position.Width = “150000” ;
container.Position.Height = “200000” ;

SubItemTable table = new SubItemTable
  (container.SubItems);
table.TableID = “Customers” ;

TableLineData dataLineNew = new
  TableLineData (table.Lines.Data);
dataLineNew.Name = “Created dynamically” ;

TableFieldText textCol = new
  TableFieldText (dataLineNew.Fields);
textCol.Contents = “Product.No” ;

TableFieldBarcode barcodeCol = new
  TableFieldBarcode (dataLineNew.Fields);
barcodeCol.Contents = “Barcode(Product.No, ‘PDF417’)” ;

Proj.Save();
Proj.Close ();
```

[More Details here...](http://www.combit.net/en/reporting-tool/List-Label-DOM)

You need at least the "[Professional](http://www.combit.net/en/page1456.aspx)"-Edition to use this feature.
i've done some nice programs with this mature software.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do I just want to tell you for new methods to do that flow this steps:

1. put your data that want to display to adapter and put adapter data to dataset
2. generate file.html code in your computer driver let c
3. populate the data which in dataset to that file according to cell that in dataset and header for dataset that is dynamic column which want to display
4. after you populate the file with data open the html file

The browser have functionality to print the page content from file-print preview
this is dynamic report just get your data you want from SQL query